# In a raffle with two prizes, what's the probability of winning at least a prize, if I buy more than one ticket?

Tags: probability

Let's say there's a raffle with two prizes. The total number of tickets sold is of 15 (meaning that the probability of winning at least  prize, if I buy one ticket, would be $p = 2/15$).

My question would be, what happens if I buy more tickets, for the same raffle? I read some answers for a similar question, and people were calculating the probability of winning the raffle, based on the probability of **not** winning it.

The formula applied there was:
$p = 1 - (1-x)^{2}$
, if someone buys two tickets. The logic behind it was: what was the probability of actually missing the prize $n$ (or **2**, for this example) times in a row. Then subtract that value from **1**.

I wanted to know, how can we calculate this probability without actually calculating the failure probability first. For example, if the probability of buying one ticket and winning one of the two prizes is $p=2/15$, why isn't the probability of winning a prize, in case of buying **2** tickets $p = 2 * 2/15$?

I know my assumption is wrong, because if someone would buy 10 tickets, the probability would already be $p=\frac{2 * 10}{15}$, which is already greater than **1**.

Why is my logic wrong, in this case?

Comment: It's wrong because you double count the scenarios in which you win two prizes.  In general, $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ but you neglected that last term.

Comment: @lulu Would $P(A)$ be the probability of winning the first prize only, and $P(B)$ the probability of winning the second prize only? If so, how can $P(A∩B)$ be explained? Probability of winning both of the prizes simultaneously?

Comment: $A$ is the event "the first ticket wins a prize" and $B$ is the event "the second ticket wins a prize".  You could only sum those probabilities if the events were mutually exclusive, which they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in essence the hypergeometric distribution; from a box with $N$ balls (15 tickets), where $m$ are white (2 winning tickets) and $N-m$ are black (13 non-winning tickets), we pick $n$ balls at random (we buy $n$ tickets). If we denote "$X$" the number of white balls (winning tickets) we pick, the probability that $X=i$ is;

$$P(X=i)=\frac{\binom{m}{i}\cdot \binom{N-m}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

So in your case it would be $P(X=1)+P(X=2)$, with substituting $n$ in the formula accordingly to the number of tickets you buy.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to instead dive into an explanation that relies more on intuition than on the necessary math behind what is happening, which should be a combination of the following:

1. You buying more tickets dilutes the individual chance of each of your tickets winning. A second ticket purchased means you would have your first ticket have to be drawn from amongst a pool of not 15 but 16 tickets instead, which lowers the individual chance of each ticket winning. Thus, you cannot simply multiply the probability of winning by the number of tickets purchsed without accounting for the fact your tickets increase the ticket total.
2. If you win the first prize with 1 ticket, all your other tickets
   become worthless for the consideration of meeting the condition on
   the 2nd raffle. The probability of winning 1 prize with 1 ticket is
   split as between winning the 1st available prize and the 2nd one.

   If on the 1st raffle you already win a prize, each of the individual
   chances of winning on the 2nd try for all the other tickets
   effectively do not matter. They are instead as if the 2nd half of
   the raffle contributes nothing to your chance of winning.

   Another way you can think of this is that the condition needs you to
   win at least 1 prize, but 2 tickets both winning means they were
   seperately counted twice towards meeting the condition despite the
   fact we only need to count this as 1 win towards our computation (if
   hypothetically every time you played you won both prizes, it
   wouldn't make sense you had a probability of 2 of winning at least 1
   prize), so you would have to remove that extra probability of 2 tickets winning.

   This effectively again reduces the additional probability
   contribution of each of your tickets.

To summarize, each ticket loses value as you buy more because 1) it has more competition against all your other tickets and 2) because two of your tickets winning is no different than 1 of your tickets winning, so you have to account for that in the computation since it would instead count it as 2 wins.

Sidenote: The logic provided is closer to the concept of expected value. If you had 10 tickets purchased in a 2 prize raffle with 15 entries (including yours), you would in fact have $E= \frac{2 \cdot 10}{15}$ prizes won on average.